# How to plot a function of two variable one defined in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How do you plot a user-defined function of two variables in Matlab?

Comment: you might find this [plot gallery](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/gallery.html) useful (click on any plot and you will see the code to produce it). In you case that would be a [surface plot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35305-matlab-plot-gallery-surface-plot-1/content/html/Surface_Plot_1.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
X, Y = meshgrid(xs, ys); % values of x and y at which we want to evaluate
Z = my_func(X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Alternatively, if your function is not vectorized,

```
X, Y = meshgrid(xs, ys); % values of x and y at which we want to evaluate
for x = 1:length(xs)
  for y = 1:length(ys)
    Z(x,y) = my_func(X(x,y), Y(x,y));
  end
end
Z = my_func(X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

Answer (score 1):

ezsurf is a simple solution, or ezmesh, or ezcontour, or ezsurfc, or ezmeshc.

Answer (score 0):

It has many types.

You can go plot gallery and select your variable and then types like mesh, 3D, surface, ...